# How to access inline subtype

Tags: typescript

I have the following generated type definition:

```
export type GetBulkLabelsGenerationDataQuery = {
    __typename?: "Query";
    orderId: string;
    fulfillment?: Maybe<{
      __typename?: "FulfillmentWithLabel";
      id: string;
      status?: Maybe<string>;
      createdAt?: Maybe<string>;
      bulkFulfillments: Maybe<{
         __typename?: "BulkFulfillmentData" | undefined;
         bId: string;
      }>;
};
```

How can I access the FulfillmentWithLabel type to set a type for a variable.

Here is the pseudo code of what I want to do:

```
const myVar: GetBulkLabelsGenerationDataQuery.FulfillmentWithLabel = {...};
```

How could I access the sub type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost right, you need square brackets and quotes.

```js
export type GetBulkLabelsGenerationDataQuery = {
    __typename?: 'Query';
    orderId: string;
    fulfillment?: Partial<{
      __typename?: 'FulfillmentWithLabel';
      id: string;
      status?: Partial<string>;
      createdAt?: Partial<string>;
    }>;
};

const myVar: GetBulkLabelsGenerationDataQuery['fulfillment'] = {
  __typename: 'FulfillmentWithLabel',
  id: '123',
};

// or use NonNullable
const myVar1: NonNullable<GetBulkLabelsGenerationDataQuery['fulfillment']>['id'] = '123';
```

Comment: How would I do the same for a nested Type that is nested in another one?
const myVar: GetBulkLabelsGenerationDataQuery['fulfillment']['xxx']  = {...}; does not work :/

Comment: the problem with nested is that `fulfillment` is optional and TS can't solve it because it may not exist. If you avoid optional from them you can access all nested stuff. Or you can use `NonNullable` for every type node.

Comment: Dammit... this is really a bummer... but I get now how it works... Thx

Comment: The NonNullable would be in the original type - right?
My use case is that the above is a server response type that is automatically generated.
And I want to use a sub type on a component where I'm sure I already have the value set... but want to check that I'm only using the allowed fields...

That's why I want to access the sub-type

Comment: NonNullable removes an optional flag from a type, so you can use it as it's shown in the answer when you need to access a nested type of an existing type. For the original type it's totally fine to keep `?` optional flag if the value can be void in the response.